# Sort map in stream by LocalDateTime

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream, java-time

I have map `Map<LocalDateTime, String>`.

How can I sort it by key values? What comparator should I use?

```
someMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(???))
```

or

```
someMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(??)
```

How can I resolve it? What should I write instead "??" ?

Sorted:

```
Key                      Value
2020-01-09 09:57:58.631  Some info
2020-01-09 09:57:59.224  Some info
2020-01-09 09:59:03.144  Info
```

Without sorting:

```
Key                     Value
2020-01-09 09:57:58.631  Some info
2020-01-09 09:59:03.144  Info
2020-01-09 09:57:59.224  Some info
```

Comment: Can you show an example of an unsorted `Map<LocalDateTime,String>`, and the sorted version of the same map?

Comment: @Hulk what should I specify in compareTo method ?

Comment: Your example is confusing. You should show the _same_ map both sorted and unsorted. Also, show which of date or string should have a higher priority. Do you sort by the dates first, and if the dates are the same, sort by the strings? Or, do you sort by the strings first, and if the strings are the same, sort by the dates?

Comment: @Sweeper No, I need sort only by dates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())` like this:

```
Map<LocalDateTime, String> collect = someMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (o1, o2) -> o1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Output

```
{2020-04-01T12:27:48.054=info, 2020-04-17T11:15:13.423=info, 2020-04-29T11:01:21.372=info}
```

Comment: Didn't know about `Map.Entry.comparingByKey()`. Nice one!

Comment: Yes it exist from [Java-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey--), thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<LocalDateTime, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 4, 17, 11, 15), "Value A");
map.put(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 4, 1, 12, 27), "Value B");
map.put(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 4, 29, 11, 1), "Value C");
    
map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).forEach(entry -> {
    System.out.println(entry);
});
```

will result in

```
2020-04-01T12:27=Value B
2020-04-17T11:15=Value A
2020-04-29T11:01=Value C
```